# what is a distribution of $X$ given $X-Y>0$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

given two normally distributed variables $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu_X,\sigma_X)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y)$ that are independent $\rho_{XY} =0$, what is a distribution of $X$ given $X>Y$.

I have run several simulations in Matlab and $X|X>Y$ looks suspiciously normally distributed, but what are its mean and standard deviation?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: I agree with comments below. Although it looks suspiciously normally distributed, it definitely isn't.

Comment: $$\mathbb P\{X\leq x\mid X-Y>0\}=\frac{\mathbb P\{X\leq x, X>Y\}}{\mathbb P\{X>Y\}}=...$$

Comment: Just a side note: _independence of two normal random variables is __not__ equivalent to their correlation being zero_ as your post tacitly suggests.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X+Y)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X-Y)$ are independent standard normals and $2 X = (X + Y) + (X-Y) = \sqrt{2} (Z_1 + Z_2),$ so what you are doing is considering (up to a multiplicative constant), the sum of two normal random variable _given_ than one of them is positive. This is not normal but sure, it will look like a translation of normal. (It will be normal if you arrume $Z_2 = 1,$ say, as opposed to $Z_2 > 0;$ not that $Z_2 \in 1 \pm \varepsilon$ will have high probability so with high probability you do see a translation of a normal distribution.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of thinking through the inequality $X>Y$, see it as $Z = X-Y>0$. Note that given that $X$ and $Y$ are both normal, $Z$ is normal with mean $\mu_x-\mu_Y$ and variance $\sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2$ (assuming independence). Thus, you can calculate
$$
\begin{aligned}
P\{X\leq x | X>Y\} &= \frac{P\{X\leq x, X>Y\}}{P\{X>Y\}}\\
&= \frac{P\{Y<X\leq x\}}{P\{Z>0\}}
\end{aligned}
$$
I assume you can work out $P\{Z>0\}$ with ease, for it is the distribution function of a normal r.v.. The hard part is $P\{Y<X\leq x\}$. You can draw the area in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to see how to integrate it. I believe it is as follows (I changed $x$ for $z$ so there is no confusion in the integrands and limits):
$$
\begin{aligned}
P\{Y<X\leq z\} &= \int_{-\infty}^z \int_{-\infty}^x f(x,y)dydx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^z \int_{-\infty}^x f(x) f(y) dydx\quad (\text{Independence})\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^z f(x) \int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^z f(x) F_Y(x) dx
\end{aligned}
$$
I do not know if this has a closed form, but you could try to calculate at least the density through Leibniz rule, but, as @fGDu94 noted, I don't think this distribution is "trivially" normal.

However, we could try to solve the simplest case, which is that where $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal r.v.. In such case, we have that
$$
\begin{aligned}
P\{Y<X\leq z\} &= \int_{-\infty}^z f(x) F_Y(x) dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^z \phi(x) \Phi(x) dx \\
&= \int_0^{\Phi(z)} u du = 0.5\Phi(z)^2
\end{aligned}
$$
where we used the variable change $u = \Phi(x)$, and thus $du = \phi(x) dx$, where $\Phi$ is the distribution function of a standard normal and $\phi$ its density. Moreover, now $Z$ has mean 0 so $P(Z>0) = 0.5$. Thus,
$$
P\{X\leq x | X>Y\} = 0.5\Phi(x)^2/0.5 = \Phi(x)^2.
$$
Then, $f(x|X>Y) = 2\Phi(x) \phi(x)$. The image below shows a plot of the standard normal density $\phi(x)$ and $f(x|X>Y)$ as given before. You can see they look very similar, as you guessed through simulation. However, the r.v. $X|X>Y$ is not normal even under the simplest of assumptions.
[image]

Comment: Nice!  But your last sentence doesn't seem to be properly justified.  Moreover the plot is tantalizingly looking like a normal with a small average around 0.5!

Comment: Ok, I tried to fiddle with the parameters in order to move one onto the other and it indeed refuses to match! https://bit.ly/3S8SXUO

Comment: Regarding the last sentence, if $Z$ is standard normal, then its density function is $\phi$. In the standard case, we have that the density of $X|X>Y$ is the product of the density and CDF of a standard normal r.v., i.e., $f(x|X>Y) = 2\Phi(x) \phi(x)\neq \phi(x)$. Their CDF differ too, and such $X|X>Y$ is not normal, given that a r.v. is characterized by its CDF.

Comment: My question actually was why isn't $2\Phi(x)\phi(x)$  a normal distribution with some other parameters?

Comment: You could do it by contradiction. Assume that there are $\mu$ and $\sigma$ such that $2\Phi(x)\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma}\phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$ (i.e. assume that the density of $X|X>Y$ is normal not necessarily standard). Then 
$$
\Phi(x) = \frac{\phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})}{2\sigma\phi(x)}
$$
displaying the CDF of a standard normal r.v. as an elementary function, giving a contradiction. This is, it gives a sort of "simple closed-form" expression of $\Phi$, which does not exist.

Comment: I did think of this argument but it is definitely using a pretty sophisticated result, isn't it?  On the other  hand I guess you may simply differentiate the RHS and check that it isn't $\phi$.

Comment: I prefer simpler proofs to avoid doing algebra or calculations as much as possible, but you are absolutely right, you could try that too to feel the result more approachable. At first I was even solving the RHS (it is all exponentials so it's relatively easy to do) to show something similar of what you're saying, but I gave up half way.

Comment: @Ruy, are you sure  bit.ly/3S8SXUO both are PDFs? Just looking on the picture, I would guess that both cannot integrate to 1, given the red looks like it dominates the blue one.

Comment: No, I didn't bother too much with coefficients, since I was just interested in the general shape of the curves.  Defining $\phi(x)=\exp(-x^2)$, the red curve it $\phi(x)\int_{-\infty}^x \phi(t)dt$, while the blue one is $a\phi(bx+c)$ with the best choice of coefficients $a,b,c$ that I could find in order to try to match the two curves.